# Set default value, if exist in config.properties use that, if overridden on command line use that

Tags: java

Untested code (just thinking out loud), but I'm thinking there must be a more elegant way to do this.

So there's three ways to set a variable:

1. just assign it
2. read it from a properties file (might not be there)
3. read it from the command line (could be more than one argument or none)

Higher number takes precedence. How would I approach this?

```java
public static final String APP_DOWNLOAD_PATH;

[...]

// If download path is not defined in config.properties, set it to the app dir.
String download = properties.getProperty("download", System.getProperty("user.dir"));

// Override if download path is set via command line.
String override = null;
try {
  override = System.getProperty("download");
} catch (NullPointerException | IllegalArgumentException ok) {
  // property is either not found or empty.
}
String APP_DOWNLOAD_PATH = (override == null || override.isEmpty()) ? download : override;
```

E: Added restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight forward approach is the best in my opinion. For example:

```
public static final String APP_DOWNLOAD_PATH = "foo";

public static void main(String... args) {

    String dwnPath = null;
    
    if(args.length > 0) {
        dwnPath = args[0];
    } else if(System.getProperty("download") != null) { // don't need try-catch, "download" is not null and not empty ("")
        // not DRY at all
        dwnPath = System.getProperty("download");
    } else {
        dwnPath = APP_DOWNLOAD_PATH;
    }

    // rest of program
}
```

The above could also be extracted to it's own function leading to a one liner:

```
String dwnPath = getDownloadPath(args, System.getProperty("download"), APP_DOWNLOAD_PATH);
```

The extracted function can also be more *elegant* than the code above:

```
/** Documentation */
public static String getDownloadPath(String[] args, String property, String default) {
    return (args.length > 0) ? args[0] : (property != null) ? property : default;
}
```

Comment: This only works when only one command line argument is given, correct? If so, I should've put that as a restriction in my question. :(

Comment: Yes but that's just because I'm only checking if `args.length` is greater than `0`. That can easily be changed to account for other circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

If it is ok to use a external library, then [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#firstNonEmpty-T...-) apache commons method could be useful -

```
StringUtils.firstNonEmpty(System.getProperty("download"), 
                          properties.getProperty("download", System.getProperty("user.dir")), 
                          "some value");
```

Comment: What happens when System.getProperty() throws an exception?

Comment: You may have another your own utility method for it which returns null when the property is missing.

Comment: @Brazen `System.getProperty(...)` will only throw an exception if you pass it `null` or the empty string (`""`), or in the rare case a `SecurityException`, which if you want to make your code airtight I guess you should account for it.

Comment: @JonnyHenly Oh, so it's about the argument, not its return value!